# ASP.NET Development Server - is the source available?

Tags: .net, asp.net, webserver, cassini, webdev.webserver

I remember several years back it was called Cassini and the source was available for download.

Is this no longer the case?  Either my Google skills are lacking or I can't seem to find the source code for it anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the source from here:

[Cassini for Framework 3.5](https://web.archive.org/web/20120511060641/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/dmitryr/archive/2008/10/03/cassini-for-framework-3-5.aspx)